# Why does USB pen partition not show up in /dev/

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive

This is a question to end my wondering, more than a problem.

I am playing around with some USB memory sticks on Linux. When inserted they are automatically mounted, and I can access the files. Two new nodes appear in /dev/: /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1. I know what this means: sdb is the second SCSI device and sdb1 is the first partition on this device.

For one single USB pen, it behaves differently. It is still mounted and I can access the files. The fs-node /dev/sdb appears, but there is no /dev/sdb1.

Why is that?

This USB memory stick is smaller than the others, 1GB versus 4GB, and is older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the usb stick has no partition table, it simply has one filesystem which spans the entire stick.